# Why does "uniq" count identical words as different?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, uniq

I want to calculate the frequency of the words from a file, where the words are one by line. The file is really big, so this might be the problem (it counts 300k lines in this example).

I do this command:

```
cat .temp_occ | uniq -c | sort -k1,1nr -k2 > distribution.txt
```

and the problem is that it gives me a little bug: it considers the same words as different.

For example, the first entries are:

```
306 continua 
278 apertura 
211 eventi 
189 murah 
182 giochi 
167 giochi
```

with `giochi` repeated twice as you can see.

At the bottom of the file it becomes even worse and it looks like this:

```
  1 win 
  1 win 
  1 win 
  1 win 
  1 win 
  1 win 
  1 win 
  1 win 
  1 win 
  1 winchester 
  1 wind 
  1 wind
```

for all the words.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to sort first:

```
cat .temp_occ | sort| uniq -c | sort -k1,1nr -k2 > distribution.txt
```

Comment: I feel stupid, thanks a lot and sorry again for the noob question

Answer (score 6):

Or use "sort -u" which also eliminates duplicates. See [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/linux.debian.user/gA9S0InWBu8%5B1-25%5D).

Answer (score 4):

The size of the file has nothing to do with what you're seeing. [From the man page of uniq(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/uniq.1.html):

> Note: 'uniq' does not detect repeated lines unless they are adjacent.
>          You may want to sort the input first, or use 'sort -u' without
>          'uniq'.  Also, comparisons honor the rules specified by 'LC_COLLATE'.`

So running `uniq` on

```
a
b
a
```

will return:

```
a
b
a
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that some of the words have whitespace characters after them? If so you should remove them using something like this:

```
cat .temp_occ | tr -d ' ' | uniq -c | sort -k1,1nr -k2 > distribution.txt
```

Comment: No I already checked that, before posting. This was what I though too, but the whitespaces are the same in all the words. The solution to use sort also before the uniq worked like a charm. Thanks for the help :)